# ImageIO is null reading ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, image, java-io

I have this piece of code

```
System.out.println  ("fileData 1 -> " + fileData);

ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);

System.out.println  ("fileData 2 -> " + in);

try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
    System.out.println  ("fileData 3 -> " + img);

....
```

and this is what I see in the console:

```
fileData 1 -> [B@7a677c
fileData 2 -> java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@203aa8
fileData 3 -> null
```

How come that `BufferedImage` is null and does not throw an Exception ?

Comment: Library decided to deliver null instead of throwing exception?   Look into sources....

Comment: Reading the documentations for ImageIO, I guess you could cast your ByteArrayInputStream to ImageInputStream.  ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is));

Comment: `fileData` is non string object and you are trying to print it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.InputStream-) says, it can be null:

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied
>   InputStream with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those
>   currently registered. The InputStream is wrapped in an
>   ImageInputStream. If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to
>   read the resulting stream, null is returned. [...]